# Is it possible to sort layers by fill color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, layers

Pretty much as the title asked, is it possible to sort layers by fill color? I would like to sort by hue starting from darker colors to lighter colors.

Comment: ***Maybe*** with scripting, but there's nothing inherent in the app to do this.

Comment: Well, normally the layers define the drawing order, so the situations where you would need this is really really small. You can definitely script this. And you should its one of those second or third try scripting jobs that have no value to others. (Mainly since objects can have multiple fills, or somebody has used a live paint object, group or clipping mask that in fact defies any logic you could come up with. So the tool needs to do several decisions only you can make, making it impossible for others to make this script for you)

Answer (score 1):

No built-in layer auto-sorting of any kind.

All the layer sorting you can do in Illustrator by default is manually moving them around in the Layers panel.

Comment: I was thinking this is the case, thank you!